# Changing element value in List<T>.ForEach ForEach method

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0

I have the following code:

```
newsplit.ToList().ForEach(x => x = "WW");
```

I would expect that all elements in the list are now "WW" but they are still the original value. How come? What do I have to do different?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Assuming that `newsplit` is an `IEnumerable<string>`, you want:

```
newsplit = newsplit.Select(x => "WW");
```

The code that you currently have is equivalent to the following:

```
foreach(string x in newsplit.ToList()) {
    AssignmentAction(x);
}

...

public static void AssignmentAction(string x) {
    x = "WW";
}
```

This method won't modify `x` because of the pass-by-value semantics of C# and the immutability of strings.

Comment: Is a string array or in my case a List<byte[]> IEnumerable as I dont think it is?

Comment: @Jon: arrays and List<T> all support the IEnumerable interface

Comment: I don't think a Select() is what Jon wants, it sounds like he wants to modify the IEnumerable itself.  Select will just give him the items that already are "WW"

Comment: @AgileJon: It sounds like you are confusing IEnumerable<T>.Where and IEnumerable<T>.Select.

Comment: @Downvoters: Two downvotes? Is this wrong? Is this harmful? What am I overlooking?

Comment: @Jason: you are right, I was confusing Select with Where.  Downvote removed.

Comment: newSplit is a list of items, in this example it is a string but I also have a List<byte[]>. I want to change each item in the List. However List<string> test = newsplit.Select(x => x = "WW"); doesn't work. Does it need to be List<string> test = newSplit.ToList().Select(x => x = "WW"); ??

Comment: @Jon: If you want to create a new List<string> with the altered values you could say List<string> test = newsplit.Select(x => "WW").ToList().

Comment: What if you already have a list and want to change its values, surely calling Select.ToList() is a bit odd as its already a list?

Answer (score 20):

Other answers have explained why your current code doesn't work. Here's an extension method which would fix it:

```
// Must be in a static non-nested class
public static void ModifyEach<T>(this IList<T> source,
                                 Func<T,T> projection)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
    {
        source[i] = projection(source[i]);
    }
}
```

Then use like this:

```
newsplit.ModifyEach(x => "WW");
```

That will work with any implementation of `IList<T>` such as arrays and `List<T>`. If you need it to work with an arbitrary `IEnumerable<T>` then you've got a problem, as the sequence itself may not be mutable.

Using `Select()` is a more functional approach of course, but sometimes mutating an existing collection *is* worth doing...

Comment: @Jon: I think you meant newsplit.ToList().ModifyEach(x => "WW") in your second code block?

Comment: @Jason: Nearly... but if you call ToList() but don't keep a reference to that new list, the modifications won't be preserved. In particular it would *not* modify the original collection. Have edited answer for intended use.

Answer (score 4):

The ForEach will allow you to manipulate the elements of the IEnumerable, but not change the reference of the element.

ie, this would set a `Foo` property of each element in the IEnumerable to the string `"WW"`:

```
newsplit.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Foo = "WW");
```

However, you won't be able to modify the values inside the IEnumerable itself.

Comment: At least in VB.Net I could only assign property of element inside ForEach if the multi-line ForEach, the Linq ForEach wouldn't assign by reference.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the LINQ expression is creating [Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx), and these are read-only. They can't be assigned to. Also, in a standard for each loop you cannot assign to a collection that is being enumerated. Try:

```
    foreach (var item in newsplit)
    {
        item = "this won't work";
    }
```

Comment: There is no anonymous type created in the given ForEach expression.  The parameter is a delegate, which is applied to each element in the iteration; and of course, won't work for the reason you give.

Comment: You are right, of course - not sure what I was thinking! But the second part, about collections being immutable when iterated, is worth noting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this:

```
newsplit = newsplit.Select(x => "WW").ToList();
```